# Why am I getting ::1 as the IP address in ASP.NET, and how to get the proper IP address?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, ip-address

I am running an ASP.NET MVC app in the localhost - dev server given with a Visual Studio. I want to get the IP address. I tried

`Request.UserHostAddress`

and

`Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")`

In both cases, I am getting::1 as a result. What is it? Why am I getting it? How can I get 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.xxx?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960019/page-request-userhostaddress-is-in-an-invalid-format

Answer (score 22):

You *are* getting a valid IP Address; `::1` is localhost for IPv6.

Comment: Well okay.. so how can I get the IPv4 IP?

Comment: OH wow! Is this working this way only because its the same machine - localhost. Will I get IPv6 address also when I deploy to prod server? I don't want the client's IPv6 address, I want their IPv4 address.. how can I get them?

Comment: [Here's a good example](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071807-1.aspx). Though the final bit showing usage needs to be changed from `IP4.GetIP4Address` to `IPNetworking.GetIP4Address()` (I use `()` even on parameterless methods in VB.NET, but the class name is the key)

Comment: but i want proper IP address? i don't want to like ::1

Answer (score 16):

What you're seeing when calling 'localhost' is valid. ::1 is the IPv6 loopback address. Equivalent to 127.0.0.1 for IPv4.

Instead of calling:

```
 http://localhost/...
```

Call:

```
http://{machinename}/...
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1/...
```

or

```
http://192.168.1.XXX/...
```

[Replace **{machinename}** with your machine's computer name. Replace **XXX** with your computer's IP address.]

Anyone calling into your machine to the MVC app will have their valid IP address as a result. If the client is an IPv6 host it will save their IPv6 IP address. If the client is an IPv4 host it will save their IPv4 IP address.

If you always want to save an IPv4 address take a look at this article on how they accomplished it with a simple class https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102847/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071807-1.aspx. You should be able to take their example and build a quick helper method to accomplish this.

Comment: Well.. I replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1 and it showed that. By machine name didn't work. I get "Unable to connect" error..

Comment: I also try this but the solution is same e I get::1

Answer (score 1):

```
Request.Params["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

instead of `Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")`

Comment: Yes. I looked into this. Basically what is happening is, your computer is using the new IP system. Localhost in IPv6 is ::1 - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/36f57ccf-7a76-4843-84bd-7bb945aad23f/. If you access from an Ipv4 client, you will get the IPv4 address instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want localhost return 127.0.0.1, maybe you need to change your "hosts" file.
You can find it in "%systemdrive%\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"

It works for me, now I get 127.0.0.1 with "Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]". I uncomment 127.0.0.1 (remove #).

Here you can find default hosts file
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034

**My file**

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

#  ::1             localhost

Comment: but i want proper IP address don like ::1? Please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

below code i have used for finding ip

```
public static string GetIp()
        {
            var Request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            try
            {

                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", new List<object> {
                    Request.UserHostAddress,
                    Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"],
                    Request.Headers["REMOTE_ADDR"]
                })
                );

                var ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
                if (Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"] != null)
                {
                    ip = Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
                    Console.WriteLine(ip + "|X-Forwarded-For");
                }
                else if (Request.Headers["REMOTE_ADDR"] != null)
                {
                    ip = Request.Headers["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                    Console.WriteLine(ip + "|REMOTE_ADDR");
                }
                return ip;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.WriteInfo("Message :" + ex.Message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get ipv6 address , after that you can find it valid ipv4 address map for ipv6 address.

c # code is below;

```
  public static string GetIP4Address(string ip) {
        try {
            var hostNames = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip);
            var ipv4 = hostNames.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            if(ipv4 != null) {
                return ipv4.ToString();
            }

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            log.WarnFormat("Error When Getting Client Ipv4");
        }

        return ip;
    }
```