# Retrieving IP address of login user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[How do you get the IP address from a request in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866980/how-do-you-get-the-ip-address-from-a-request-in-asp-net?rq=1)

```
private string GetUserIP()
{
    string ipList = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipList))
    {
        return ipList.Split(',')[0];
    }

    return Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

I always receive `null` in return of the above function. I am expecting the value i.e `192.168.1.100`

I replace the above internal code with `return Request.UserHostAddress;` and I receive `::1`

Comment: When you are working on a local webserver with IPv6 installed, `::1` *is* the user's IP address.  In IPv6 `::1` is the localhost address, just as `127.0.0.1` is the localhost address in IPv4.  Use `Request.UserHostAddress` when you're connecting from a different computer and see what you get.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795534/why-am-i-getting-1-as-ip-address-in-asp-net-and-how-to-get-the-proper-ip-add

Comment: Thats because you're connecting locally. Hop on another machine and you'll see the IP address.

Comment: @Corey Thank you, but how can I test the application under development in this specific case if I don't have another computer ?

Comment: @AspAsp `Request.UserHostAddress` should be a valid IP address for the connected client.  Testing in a single-computer environment is often difficult, since your development webserver may not bind to external addresses.  Try connecting to the webserver using your computer's IP address - `http://192.168.0.1:<portnumber>` instead of `http://localhost:<portnumber>` for instance.

Comment: are you testing this at you local machine

Comment: SatpalSingh yes, I am. 
@Corey Thank you, I see how to work with it now.